# Data scrubbing in SSRS

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I have a report that reads data from an oracle database.

One of the tables that is used for a parameter appears to have an invalid value in the XML string that is returned from the query.

'box', hexadecimal value 0x10, is an invalid character.  Line 1, position 339820

I am trying to scrub at the query level, prior to loading the parameter drop down using this query

```
select make_code, 
REGEXP_REPLACE(MAKE_TYPE_DESC,'[^ -~]','') as MAKE_TYPE_DESC  
from make_type 
order by MAKE_TYPE_DESC
```

I only want the decimal characters 32-126 (space to tilde) characters in the results.

If i take the parameter query out of the report, the report runs ok,
when i place the parameter query in, the report fails.

I am lost in this process, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:   Added screen shot
[image: screen shot of error]

Comment: can you show some sample data that is causing this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `\s` for the space?